# Two different ways of declaring an array

Tags: java, arrays

```
int arr[] = new int[6];  
int[] arr = new int[6];
```

What is difference between them?

If there is no difference then what is the purpose of having two different ways?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The difference is if you have multiple declarations.  Otherwise it is a matter of taste

```
int[] a, b[]; // a is int[], b is int[][]
int a[], b[]; // a is int[], b is int[]
```

The `int[]` is preferred in Java. The older `int a[]` is to make C programmers happy. ;)

Confusingly you can write the following, due to obscure backward bug compatibility reasons.  Don't do it.

```
public int method()[] {
    return new int[6];
}
```

Comment: Knew this one,but just to confirm, I opened eclipse and tried..Meanwhile... you took 14 upvotes :)

Comment: @PrasadKharkar Only fast people survive :D

Comment: Yeah, I'll become faster :) definitely...

Answer (score 8):

Nothing. The latter is to make C programmers get used to Java :)

See this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2), it answers your question.

Important thing to note:

```
int[] happyArray1, happyArray2;
int happyArray[], happyInt;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just some "sugar" that Java gives the programmers. It works exactly the same way and is equally efficient. It just makes it easier to learn the syntaxes.